# Use Bean inside Managed Bean

Tags: jsf-2, javabeans, managed-bean

how can i use a bean inside other bean ?

I use this solution, what's the best way ?

```
@ManagedBean(name="firstBean")
public class FirstBean implements Serializable{

  @ManagedProperty(value="#{myBean}")
  private MyBean myBean;
  ...
  //(get/set method)
}
```

I'm new in JSF and JSP so probably it's a bad practies.

Comment: Sorry !!! I delete previusly post-answe. Write again to take points...

Comment: It's perfectly fine. Your performance problem is caused by something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is the right one to inject another bean.

You only need the setter for the injected bean.

Are you having any issues\errors with it?

Comment: No, but the page is very slow. I'm using MySQL + Hybernate + JSF. I'm looking for what's the problem...